# Base64 encode/decode results in corrupted output

Tags: go

I'm trying to write some convenience wrapper funcs that `base64` encodes and decodes byte slices. (Can't understand why this is not conveniently provided in the stdlib.)

However this code (in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CQbBzfcrkU)):

```
func b64encode(b []byte) []byte {
    encodedData := &bytes.Buffer{}
    encoder := base64.NewEncoder(base64.URLEncoding, encodedData)
    defer encoder.Close()
    encoder.Write(b)
    return encodedData.Bytes()
}

func b64decode(b []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    dec := base64.NewDecoder(base64.URLEncoding, bytes.NewReader(b))
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    _, err := io.Copy(buf, dec)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return buf.Bytes(), nil
}


func main() {
    b := []byte("hello")
    e := b64encode(b)
    d, err := b64decode(e)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not decode: %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(d))
}
```

generates truncated output when I try to print it:

```
hel
```

What's going on?

Comment: Did you look at the examples for https://godoc.org/encoding/base64#example-Encoding-DecodeString and https://godoc.org/encoding/base64#example-Encoding-EncodeToString ?

Comment: don't want to cast it back and forth to string tbh.

Comment: I feel that pain... but specifically you don't need to create a new decoder each time. You can use the default ones (https://godoc.org/encoding/base64#pkg-variables) and use `Decode` and `Encode`. Then you don't have to worry about closing the encoder yourself.

Comment: `Can't understand why this is not conveniently provided in the stdlib` -- It is:  `base64.StdEncoding.Encode(dst, src []byte)` and `base64.StdEncoding.Decode(dst, src []byte) error`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The defer executes when the function ends. That is AFTER the return statement has been evaluated.

The following works: https://play.golang.org/p/sYn-W6fZh1

```
func b64encode(b []byte) []byte {
    encodedData := &bytes.Buffer{}
    encoder := base64.NewEncoder(base64.URLEncoding, encodedData)
    encoder.Write(b)
    encoder.Close()
    return encodedData.Bytes()
}
```

---

That being said, if it really is all in memory, you can avoid creating an encoder entirely. Instead, you can do something like:

```
func b64encode(b []byte) []byte {
    ret := make([]byte, base64.URLEncoding.EncodedLen(len(b)))
    base64.URLEncoding.Encode(ret, b)
    return ret
}
```

An added benefit of doing it this way it it is more efficient since it only needs to allocate once. It also allows you to no longer ignore errors in the `Write` and `Close` methods.

Comment: Nice catch. When dealing with Close-ables, I personally follow the convention: if you know you can close it now, do it... defer (too) if something could cause the function to return early. Close-ables are __always__ (AFAIK) idempotent, and you might as well free up whatever it cleans up ASAP anyway.

Comment: I like the second approach, tried that initially — but do you know why it appends an extra byte at the end? https://play.golang.org/p/5wZOrcFz0Z is it because it's not possible to calculate the length exactly before hand?

Comment: Correct. I focused on encoding since that is the one you made a mistake on the first time. Anyways, given only the encoded data's length, you can only get the decoded length within 3 bytes. The DecodedLen function returns the largest possible value.